# View files merged automatically by git

Tags: git

When after a "git pull" you get the message:

```
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

how can you know which ones were the files in conflict? I'd like to be able to check what changes git made to my files...

Comment: That information isn't recorded anywhere. However, you can checkout the old commits and redo a merge to see which files would have been in conflict.

Comment: I upvoted this question because your username is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the word "conflict": if the `git merge` step of `git pull` completed automatically, there either weren't any *conflicts*, or you have `git rerere` turned on and git *re*used *re*corded *re*solutions to resolve the conflicts.  I *suspect* you mean "how do I see what changes git brought in from the merged-in `origin/branch` part".

That is, suppose the commit graph looks like this after the `git fetch` step of a `git pull`.  Each single letter here represents a commit, and I've assumed you made two commits (`A` and `B`) since the last time you and your upstream were in sync, and they made two commits (`C` and `D`):

```
              A - B   <-- branch
            /
... - o - o
            \
              C - D   <-- origin/branch
```

At this point your `git pull` did its second half, the `git merge`, to produce a new merge commit.  Let's call this `M`:

```
              A - B
            /       \
... - o - o           M   <-- branch
            \       /
              C - D   <-- origin/branch
```

Presumably you know what changes you made, and you want to see what changes `M` has, when compared with `B` (your most recent change).

To find out, you start by finding the SHA-1 ID of commit `B`, and then you can simply run `git diff <id-of-B> branch`.  (The name `branch` finds commit `M` easily, so it's `B` that you need to find, to ask git for this diff.)

There's actually an easy way to find `B`'s ID.  `B` is always the "first parent" of `M`.  A merge commit like `M` has at least *two* parent commits, and the *first* one is the one that was the tip of your branch, before you (or `git pull`) ran `git merge <whatever>`.  (The second parent is commit `D` here, as that is what you merged-in.)  There's a special syntax in git for referring to first-parents—actually two such syntaxes, but lets use the `^` syntax for now:

```
$ git diff branch^ branch
```

The name `branch` identifies a particular commit, namely `M`.  Each `^` added *after* something that identifies a particular commit means "now go to that thing's first parent", so `branch^` identifies commit `B`.  If you want to find commit `A`, add another `^` to get `branch^^`.  To find the right-most `o` commit you can write `branch^^^`, and so on.

You can compress this notation a bit more: `branch~3` means `branch^^^`, i.e., three suffix `^`s; `branch~5` means `branch^^^^^`, and so on.

What if you want to find the *second* parent of `M`, i.e., commit `D` in the drawing above?  You can add a number after the `^` to say *which* parent: `branch^2` is commit `D`.  (If you ask for `branch^3` you get an error as commit `M` has only two parents, not three.  Merges *can* have more than two parent commits, but those are unusual.)

If you want to find commit `C`, you can start by using `branch^2` to find `D`, then add another `^`: `branch^2^` identifies commit `C`.  Since `C`'s parent is the right-most `o` commit, `branch^2^^` identifies commit `o`, just like `branch^^^` or `branch~3`.

(You can see all of this using `git rev-parse`, which prints out the full 40-character SHA-1 ID of any git object, given a name that resolves to that object.  Just run `git rev-parse <name>`.  This is a read-only operation, so you can play with it in one window while looking at the graph in another window, for instance.  Also, have a look at [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).)